# What does make up an applicaion (in traditional sense) in SharePoint? [Do not mix up with Web Application]

Tags: sharepoint, architecture

[NOTE: I am not using word 'Application' to mean what is called a 'Web Application' in SharePoint terminology. Word 'Application' is used in general sense.]

In mainstream application development platforms (like ASP.NET, Java EE) there is clear concept of an application and application boundaries.

What a SharePoint application is made up of? Sites? Lists? Features? Libraries?

A SharePoint solution can include more than one Features. Can a set of related Features be called an application? Is there a way to define what Features are related or inter-dependent?

This is not just a theoretical question. Boundary around application are needed for measuring resource utilization, controlling access, assuring SLAs (performance, availability etc.), change control, application ownership, application life-cycle management and more.

Comment: Your question makes many assumptions which are clearly invalid. The concept of "application" is not that clear cut, especially in the case of SharePoint, where you might do better to discuss a "solution". Consider: what if, in order to meet customer needs, I have to create more than one "application" (a data entry application and the admin application for it, as an example).

Comment: I do see that my question is somewhat invalid if you look from SharePoint glasses. I am not worried about the the definition of "application", what I am worried about is the implications of not having the boundaries.

Comment: I do agree that use of word "Solution" is more meaningful in the context of SharePoint. However the point remains the same - is there a logical separation among *solutions*? Is it clear - what makes up a solution? What is the life-cycle of a solution? Is solution merely package related features? If yes, after deployment can you identify what features were part of the so-called solution?

Comment: Yes, there's a separation, but it's a _logical_ separation, not physical. A solution would contain what you _want_ it to contain. And, yes, you can determine what makes up a solution - features are described by a manifest.

Comment: In general, you are being much too rigid in your definitions and in your thinking. The fact that _you_ require such rigid boundaries does not imply that such boundaries are always important, or even valuable.

Answer (score 0):

One definition can be based on hosting location. Is it hosted on SharePoint Server? Server side, it could be a solution build on SharePoint object model; client side could be based on client object model, SOAP web srevices or WCF services. Further, an application build on these paradigms could be a web, windows or console application or a web service. Performance and availability depends on host variable too.

In SharePoint there is a clear concept of boundaries, depending on your classifications and definitions. Your confusion stems from compairing technologies with product. ASP.NET, J2EE are technologies. SharePoint is a product built on a stack of technologies. Any large scale product built on many underlying technologies is no different from SharePoint.

From dev point of view boundaries could be around representation of data or management of content or both - a direct derivative of scope of your solution. Inter-dependency of features, customisations does not constitute part of one application alone. Extending SharePoint could involve dependency on existing feautures or building new ones. It is designers prerogative to define boundaries based on scope and whether to reuse existing functionality. My definition of an application would be a business case and a technical solution.

You didn't clariy what kind of resource utilisation you want to measure, it is instrumentation or project management? Change management is part of project management for development efforts. I am not even talking about Services here. In this sense any custom solution that aims to modify the default or current customised deployment of SharePoint will have a boundry defined by the changes it is bringing in.

Comment: I did not find clear answer in your response. However, I did find a good clarification point - ASP.NET, J2EE are technologies. SharePoint is a product built on a stack of technologies.

If we view SharePoint as a product, it looks like this product is intended to be used by more than one lines of business (LoBs). In addition to that SharePoint is offering lots of application development capabilities. If more than one LoBs are creating more than one solutions on the same SharePoint product, where is the boundaries around the solutions?

Comment: Finding out how much resources (CPU, IO, Memory) a particular application is using is critical aspect of managing an IT infrastructure. In SharePoint there is no way to find resource utilization of a *solution*. This is primarily because there is no clear boundaries around solution. 
Other concerns in my questions are on the same line of thought - change control, application ownership, application life-cycle management etc.